# As per hinduism, does life span of human depends on his respiratory breaths?

Tags: yoga

According to hinduism life span of every individual human depends on his respiratory breaths?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as per Yoga and Tantras. One thing that matters is the "distance of our breaths".

See, the following commentary by Sir John Woodroffe (also known as Arthur Avalon), which is taken from the introduction portion of the book "Mahanirvana Tantram - The Tantra of the Great Liberation", under the heading PRANAYAMA.

> From pranayama (q.v.) arises laghava (lightness).
>
> All beings say the ajapa Gayatri, which is the expulsion of the breath
>   by Hangkara, and its inspiration by Sahkara, 21,600 times a day.
>   Ordinarily, the breath goes forth a distance of 12 fingers breadth,
>   but in singing, eating, walking, sleeping, coition, the distances are
>   16, 20, 24, 30, and 36 breadths respectively. In violent exercise
>   these distances are exceeded, the greatest distance being 96 breadths.
>   **Where the breathing is under the normal distance, life is prolonged. Where it is above that, it is shortened.** Puraka is inspiration, and
>   rechaka expira-tion. Kumbhaka is the retention of breath between these
>   two movements. Kumbhaka is, according to the Gheranda Sanghita of
>   eight kinds: sahita, suryyabheda, ujjayi, shitali, bhastrika,
>   bhramari, murchchha, and kevali.

Comment: Sri Ramakrishna said that birth death and marriage are determined by God.Yes Yogis claim that Kumbhaka lengthens life as mentioned by saints like Devraha Baba.But Adi Sankara, Sri Chaitanya, Sri Ramakrishna, Swami Vivekananda all left bodies within 50:)

Comment: @Partha what Sri Ramakrishna has said is true, but another thing which is also true is true Yogis are no less than God ..  but of course we do not know abt such Yogis, they do not write books neither do they live among us,

Comment: yes real yogis are known to rise above Prakriti